# Spark job failing : Failed to create local tmp dir

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I was trying to run a long running Spark Job using YARN. After few hours of execution, I get exception below :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create local dir in /tmp

Permission issue should not be there as Nodemanager and application is running as root and /tmp dir should be writable.
```

`/tmp Dir` has enough space on all nodemanagers.

Update 1 :
After reading the complete logs, I found connection with some executor(read nodes) were lost and then it started deleting temporary data and it started failing.

DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1568187536265_0302/blockmgr-b9c691dd-8f39-4962-8799-014a553505fe/3d/temp_shuffle_5807636d-917a-4f7a-b8bc-c3984b642243
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1568187536265_0302/blockmgr-b9c691dd-8f39-4962-8799-014a553505fe/3d/temp_shuffle_5807636d-917a-4f7a-b8bc-c3984b642243 (No such file or directory) .

19/09/12 12:02:23 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 123.1 in stage 10.0 (TID 5712)
java.io.IOException: Failed to create local dir in /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1568187536265_0302/blockmgr-87e8c520-408b-4582-a370-5afcb06ced8f/2f.

Comment: Even though you run the application as root, the application is running by yarn and is possible to have a permission issue. Make a tmp directory with 777 permission and try again.

Comment: can you please provide complete log error? i don't think this is an error.

Comment: is this because of connection lost  or slave lost ? please post full log

Comment: Yarn is also running as root so that doesn't looks like an issue.